# C# ASPX Downloading files from localhost

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to download a file (.txt) from my web service. My web service works with this code

```
WebClient req = new WebClient();
HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" +
    fileName);
Response.WriteFile("C:\\Temp\\Storage\\" + (fileName));
Response.End();
```

and i would like to call it from the client. How is that done?

Comment: Have you tried using the [WebClient.DownloadFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) method, and if so, what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://NikUser.com/myfile.txt"), @"c:\myfile.txt");
}
```

Try it .... hopes it will work ...